# Handling questions that are answered in comments and likely to fester

Tags: discussion

[Here is a question asked by a very low rep user. The answer was trivial, provided in a comment and acknowledged as a solution by the asker.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599359/xor-matrix-multiplication-in-python)

What do you do in this case?

- Any subsequent answer will likely be rep-whore.
- Its futile to merge an answer in as the asker may not accept it.

Vote to close and move on? Flag to delete on account of its triviality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first encourage the commenter to add their answer as a real answer. If, after some time, they have not done so, I would add it as a community-wiki answer, referencing the comment with the answer in it. Then the answer exists as an actual answer, but you will not be harvesting reputation for it.

Comment: Good point I forgot about the community wiki option!

Comment: One point to add.  In several such cases, the question would be a faq of sorts and it should be trivial to find a duplicate that answers the question.